# find changed folder in git

Tags: git, gitlab

scenario: The source code is on GitHub and the pipeline is on Gitlab.
on every pipeline run: script clones the repository and does some operations.

The main goal is to identify changed directories. I tried `git diff --quiet HEAD^ HEAD – “$dirs”`, and it works only in case all changes are with one commit and then pushed.

If there are many commits before the push operation. accordingly, my git diff command only returns the last modified folder.
what could be a workaround?

p.s Gitlab pipeline triggered from GitHub action, on push operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
*--*--X--*--*--* <- main
       \
        *--*--* <- feature
```

Most often, the changes you want to inspect are the changes between `feature` and *the fork point between `feature` and `main`* (commit indicated as `X` in diagram above)

There is a syntax for `git diff` to get that ([documentation here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203-1)):

```
git diff origin/main...feature  # three dots, not a typo
```

---

if you intend to run this action in a CI job:

most runners integrate some form of shallow cloning by default, you may have to do a few more actions before :

- you may need to explicitly fetch the `main` branch separately to have a local copy of `origin/main`:

```
git fetch --depth=100 origin main
```

- you may need to deepen the number of commits on your current branch:

```
git fetch --depth=100 origin feature
```

Comment: in my case i have not cloned repository before... i am cloning repository during execution of pipline

Answer (score 0):

can you try this - `git show --pretty="" --name-only <commit-sha/tag-name>`

It should lists all the filenames which are changed. unfortunately, we can't provide branch name in the place of <commit-sha/tag-name>